# change configuration of CherryPy base service without restart

Tags: config, cherrypy

I have CherryPy based web service which dishes out data from flat files based on GET request  query's. The list of files that it uses as its database is specified in a yaml based configuration file.

Now each time I want to add/remove  a file from that yaml config file, I have edit the yaml configuration file and then restart the service.

What would be the easiest way for me to implement a scheme, so that each time I modify the config file to the configuration file, the web service would automatically detect the change and reload the contents of that file without requiring a restart.

My goal is to avoid downtime completely and not interrupt my customers who are running the queries.

Comment: When you say "data from files" does that mean you're using the staticdir Tool? Or do you read in all the files and do some sort of transformations before serving data in, say, HTML from your page handler? Would it be too costly to read in the files on each request? The answers to each of those will guide the answer to your main question.

Answer (score 0):

If your service is behind the apache using mod_rewrite:
create two instance of your application with different ports, and when *mod_rewrite* is configured to rewrite requests to instance A, you can change instance B config file, after auto-restart, you can change the apache config file, and issue:

```
/etc/init.d/apache reload
```

then change instance A's config file.

If your cherrypy is standalone you can use proxy server with mentioned two instance.

Comment: I used another solution. What we did was, that each time a new file needs to be added to config, we query a URL withn our app, whose sole purpose is to update the config with the new file and add the contents of the file to the database.